# Spring HATEOAS with nested resources and JsonView filtering

Tags: java, spring, jackson, hateoas, json-view

I am trying to add HATEOAS links with `Resource<>`, while also filtering with `@JsonView`. However, I don't know how to add the links to nested objects.

In the project on [on Github](https://github.com/helo478/SpringSampleProject), I've expanded on [this project](https://github.com/madanrajs/SpringSampleProject) (adding in the open pull request to make it work without nested resources), adding the "Character" entity which has a nested `User`.

When accessing the `~/characters/resource-filtered` route, it is expected that the nested `User` "player" appear with the `firstNm` and `bioDetails` fields, and with Spring generated links to itself, but without the `userId` and `lastNm` fields.

I have the filtering working correctly, but I cannot find an example of nested resources which fits with the `ResourceAssembler` paradigm. It appears to be necessary to use a `ResourceAssembler` to make `@JsonView` work.

Any help reconciling these two concepts would be appreciated. If you can crack it entirely, consider sending me a pull request.

User.java

```
//package and imports
...

public class User implements Serializable {

    @JsonView(UserView.Detail.class)
    private Long userId;

    @JsonView({ UserView.Summary.class, CharacterView.Summary.class })
    private String bioDetails;

    @JsonView({ UserView.Summary.class, CharacterView.Summary.class })
    private String firstNm;

    @JsonView({ UserView.Detail.class, CharacterView.Detail.class })
    private String lastNm;

    public User(Long userId, String firstNm, String lastNm) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.firstNm = firstNm;
        this.lastNm = lastNm;
    }

    public User(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    ...
    // getters and setters
    ...

}
```

CharacterModel.java

```
//package and imports
...

@Entity
public class CharacterModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(CharacterView.Summary.class)
    private Long characterId;

    @JsonView(CharacterView.Detail.class)
    private String biography;

    @JsonView(CharacterView.Summary.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(CharacterView.Summary.class)
    private User player;

    public CharacterModel(Long characterId, String name, String biography, User player) {
        this.characterId = characterId;
        this.name = name;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.player = player;
    }

    public CharacterModel(Long characterId) {
        this.characterId = characterId;
    }

    ...
    // getters and setters
    ...
}
```

CharacterController.java

```
//package and imports
...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/characters")
public class CharacterController {

    @Autowired
    private CharacterResourceAssembler characterResourceAssembler;

    ...

    @JsonView(CharacterView.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resource-filtered", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Resource<CharacterModel> getFilteredCharacterWithResource() {
        CharacterModel model = new CharacterModel(1L, "TEST NAME", "TEST BIOGRAPHY", new User(1L, "Fred", "Flintstone"));
        return characterResourceAssembler.toResource(model);
    }

    ...
}
```

CharacterResourceAssembler.java

```
//package and imports
...

@Component
public class CharacterResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<CharacterModel, Resource<CharacterModel>>{

    @Override
    public Resource<CharacterModel> toResource(CharacterModel user) {
        Resource<CharacterModel> resource = new Resource<CharacterModel>(user);
        resource.add(linkTo(CharacterController.class).withSelfRel());
        return resource;
    }

}
```